# Is it possible to "assign" a function to another function?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, animation

I'm pretty new to coding and I'm looking for advice.

I'm having a set of functions inside an animation loop that are executed depending on a variable value. This means I'm actually checking the value each frame and execute the associated function.

Since the value of the variable only changes on user input, I was thinking about taking the if else - statement out of the animation loop. I was wondering if I could "assign" the associated function to another function that runs in the loop but is able to change its content.

Any thoughts on this? :-)

Comment: what do you mean by a set of functions, like one function definition after the other, inside the loop? and what exactly do you mean "executed depending on a variable value"? Do you mean like `if(myValue=="doThisFunction") thisFunction()`, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions in JavaScript are objects. That means variables can refer to functions.¹

So if you have functions `a`, `b`, and `c`, you can have a `current` variable referring to the one you're currently using, for instance, `a`:

```
let current = a;
```

Later, if things change, you can update `current` to refer to `b` instead:

```
current = b;
```

Either way, you then use `current` exactly like you'd use `a` or `b`:

```
current(/*arguments go here if any*/);
```

Live Example:

```js
const btnCall = document.getElementById("btnCall");
let current;

useA();

function a() {
    console.log("Function `a` called");
}

function b() {
    console.log("Function `b` called");
}

function useA() {
    current = a;
    btnCall.value = "Call a";
}

function useB() {
    current = b;
    btnCall.value = "Call b";
}

hook("btnCall", () => {
    current();
});
hook("btnUseA", useA);
hook("btnUseB", useB);

function hook(id, fn) {
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("click", fn);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Call ?" id="btnCall">
<input type="button" value="Use a" id="btnUseA">
<input type="button" value="Use b" id="btnUseB">
```

[Also on CodePen](https://codepen.io/tjcrowder/pen/KKdrYdX) (snippets are down for a lot of people right now).

---

¹ In fact, any time you're not using an object property to refer to a function, you're always using a "variable" (more accurately, a *binding*) to refer to a function. When you do:

```
function example() {
}
```

...you're creating a function and a variable in the current scope that refers to the function. The variable created by a function declaration like that is effectively identical to a `var` variable. Variables (`var`, `let`), constants (`const`), and function parameters are all *bindings* that hold values, including references to objects such as functions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it will help you but you can give it a try
Create an object that holds that functions you want in the value and the key to each function should be the value from the input.
for example:

```js
let obj = {
    someValue : function1,
    someOtherValue: function2
} 
function function1(){
    console.log('function 1')
}

function function2(){
    console.log('function 2')
}

function getUserInput(value){
    obj[value]();
}
getUserInput('someValue');
getUserInput('someOtherValue');
```

Comment: Using an object or a Map that you look the function up in each time is also a reasonable approach, nice one. I've fixed a couple of typos in the snippet and added a second function for clarity.